# How to Upgrade linux fedora 14 to the latest version

Tags: linux, fedora

I just bought a live CD of fedora linux and found out that it's a 2010 version (fedora 14) which may not allow me to enjoy linux fully. I'm still kind of lost  because I've been looking for ways to upgrade the fedora 14 to fedora 22 but yet to found one.

Please , can anyone help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Fedora has a wiki page on how to upgrade using `dnf`, although, I am not sure if this will work for Fedora 14. https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade

Comment: Don't do that. Install Fedora 23 from scratch. You will save yourself a lot of troubles.

Answer (score 2):

I think that fedora 14 repos are offline (end of support reached), you should really consider downloading a fedora 22 iso and either do a fresh install or upgrade using that image.

Anyway if you want to try to upgrade here is the command:

```
$ sudo yum install fedora-upgrade 
$ sudo fedora-upgrade
```

EDIT: dnf will not work in fedora 14 (it was introduced only last year IIRC)

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother/waste your time with any upgrade path - especially from that far back. It sounds like you don't have much invested in it yet (loading lots of apps, etc). Do a fresh install. [Download](https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/) the 23 live image and go from there.

I had Fedora 9 on my box at home for a long time before I finally upgraded. It's wasn't smart to wait that long, but it was lazy. When I went to 22, I did not even bother to upgrade, I did a fresh install.

To 23 there is an easy path to upgrade to the next version, or so they say. I haven't tried it yet, but I will soon as I have 22 on my home box now.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used fedora, so I'm not sure, but I would be really surprised if they supported upgrades from 14 to 22 in one step. Most linux distributions (I know of) only support upgrading from one major version to the next. Even if you could find all those versions, upgrading 14->15->16->17->18->19->20->21->22 would take a long time, and probably involving downloading more data than just downloading an iso of 22. So forget about using that old cd, and go to [getfedora.org](https://getfedora.org) and download a new version (the newest seems to be 23).

Comment: As of a few releases ago, we officially support skipping one, but not more than that. And there's definitely no promises going from way back to 14.